# Linux: How to concatenate several lists of files according to file name?

Tags: linux, shell, concatenation

I have a list of several hundred files that belong to roughly 20 groups:

```
file_1_1
file_2_1
file_3_1
...
file_22_2
file_23_2
...
file_900_20
file_901_20
...
```

the number of files in each group (last number) is flexible. It is also crucial that the files are sorted by the first number before concatenation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is not that clear what you are asking - should all files named file_x_1 be concatenated together, then all files named file_x_2, etc, so you have ~20 output files?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to concatenate files with the same suffix into a combined file:

```
for i in {1..20}
do
    cat file_*_$i > combined_$i
done
```

Comment: Depending on the locale, this may not sort properly on the first number following 'file_'.

Comment: that's what I'm most worried about. I'll try this out later. Any tipps to make sure that the sorting is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job

```
dir="./manyfiles"
export LC_ALL=C
while read num group
do
    cat $dir/*_${num}_${group} >> combined_${group}
done < <(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -name \*_*_* -print | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1)," ",$NF}' | sort -k2,2n -k1,1n)
```

I hope than understand correctly your needs...